# Reading through files quickly

Tags: c++, c, file, input, scanf

My question is : how to read files longer than 50 MB **quickly** (i.e. in about a second) by using a C++ or C program...

What I'm interested in is files, which contain plain integers...

I have already ruled out ifstream, cause it's far too slow for this purpose (8-9 secs).

Currently, I'm using fscanf, but still, it's very very slow (4 secs)....

I'm 100 % sure that the way files are read is the problem, and I'm not I/O bound.

Can you suggest any alternatives?

**EDIT**

File format:

```
1 2 41 2 1 5 1 2 ... (integers)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What is the format of the file?

Comment: What makes you think you're not I/O bound? Have you profiled it?

Comment: Ahh, not yet, but if you divide 50MB with 3.5 secs, it does't really make sense... Also, I've tested it in 4 different PC's ....

Comment: Egh. This is the second time this week someone has thought a tiny example is a thorough description of their file format. For instance, these could be any strings of decimal digits (with possibly + or -) separated by any number of any other characters, or they could be strictly positive decimal numbers, guaranteed to be representable by `int` on this platform, strictly separated by a single space character.

Comment: Get a faster hard drive? Nobody can possibly hope to answer this question as the number of seconds an algorithm takes to run depends entirely on your hardware, OS, compiler, and other environmental factors.

Comment: I only need to read ints. Plain ints represented as ints. BTW...I tested it on a pc using an SSD... The same result...

Answer (score 2):

Try using memory mapped files. Try googling

```
CreateFileMapping
MapViewOfFile
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it should be a comment. Also, (s?)he hasn't said which platform is being used. Not everyone uses Windows! But anyway, that doesn't really "read" the file, if I understand correctly. It makes it "look" like memory, but you will still have to go over the whole thing, pulling it from disk to memory, to parse the integers (although it is possible this will be faster).

Comment: He. And I'm using both Win and Linux...

Answer (score 1):

To read in data faster you have to reduce the quantity of reads and increase the amount of data reading.

Assuming a worst case, the hard drive has to initialize for every read command:

- The platters have to come up to speed (takes time).
- The OS reads the directory structure.
- The OS searches the directory structure for your file.
- The OS tells the hard drive which sector or platter & sector to read
  from.
- The hard drive waits for the start of the sector, then reads
  contiguous data from the start of the sector.
- The hard drive spins down.

Everything but reading from the sector is considered overhead.  The overhead would be applied for reading whether one byte is read or 10k is read.  The efficiency is to keep the drive spinning, which means reading more data per "read" command.

The are many methods to optimize this:

- Single large buffer -- read a lot of data into a single buffer and
  parse the buffer.
- Double Buffering or Multiple Buffering -- Use multiple buffers so one
  thread can parse one buffer while another thread reads data into
  another buffer.
- Memory Mapped files -- The OS manages file reading as if it were
  memory.

Other methods outside of your program:

- Optimize the file data structure for efficient reading by using fixed
  record sizes.
- Reduce the number of fragments in the file -- aim for one huge
  contiguous area on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it matter what this file contains? Reading a 54Mb file took half a second with this *very* quick-and-dirty standard C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned char *big_file = NULL;
size_t length;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *f;
    clock_t start_time, end_time;
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        start_time = clock();
        f = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
        if (f)
        {
            fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
            length = ftell(f);
            fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
            big_file = (unsigned char *)malloc(length);
            if (big_file)
            {
                if (fread (big_file, 1,length, f) == length)
                    printf ("successfully read %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long)length);
                free (big_file);
            }
            fclose (f);
        }
        end_time = clock() - start_time;
        printf ("this took %f second(s)\n", ((double)end_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
successfully read 54721618 bytes
this took 0.523000 second(s)
```

Be warned: running it a second time on the *same* file returns this:

```
successfully read 54721618 bytes
this took 0.037000 second(s)
```

With this, your question may need to be rephrased: "okay so I can *read* fast, but I need to do XXX on that data" -- and if "XXX" = "a lot", you may go over the 0.477 seconds that remain within the 1-second time allotment.

Comment: Actually that can be really fast indeed.... However, i only need to read the data in less than 1 second, the time it takes to do the processing is almost negligible.